# How to register participant for all repeating/recurring events - CiviCRM 4.6

Tags: civievent, 4.6

I've been looking at [the docs](http://gitbook.civicrm.org/events/manual-event-registration.html) but can't find an obvious way to register someone onto all occurrences of a repeating/recurring event.

e.g. On a ten week course, I want to register them on one page, and not have to register them 10 times

Comment: I've spoken to Veda who have been developing recurring events. I can confirm at the moment registering one participant onto a series of events is not yet possible, but is planned. Will update this question when this changes!

Comment: any update jon-man

Answer (score 2):

At the moment recurring events don't support registering a participant onto all/some occurrences through the registration process. Its a feature thats been requested a few times and we're looking for funding to make it happen. Please get in touch if your interested.

Answer (score -1):

If an event lasts 10 weeks, and only a single registration is required, you don't need to set it up as a parent event plus 9 recurrences. A single event registration will do and just show the start and end dates on the Information and Settings pages.

If you need to have the attendee register for each week individually, I'd use the Import Participants feature to mass register them for all events.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Is there an easy way to register one person onto all 10 weeks of the source, rather than one week at a time?

Comment: If you don't need to have each week as a separate event, then you create your event to LAST 10 weeks and just register them once.

Comment: and if you need some sort of 'did x show up in week y' you could do that just a custom field on the event